# Getting log4j2 logging pattern format from an external package or file

Tags: logging, log4j2, logback

I'm currently migrating an existing `logback` logging configration to `log4j2`.
In there the logging format is specified from an `external file`.

In the older logback system..

```xml
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
    <layout class="com.abc.logging.MyJsonLayout">
      <pattern>%msg</pattern>
    </layout>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

Where in the `<layout class="com.abc.logging.MyJsonLayout">` tag, `com.abc.logging.MyJsonLayout` points to the package where the format of logging is specified. And above `logback` configuration is logging to the format specified in that file without any issue.

What I need is to apply the same pattern from the same package for `log4j2` configuration.
I read the Apache docs regarding about this and couldn't find any helpful information.

So is there a way that I can specify the path of this package as a pattern format in a the `log4j2.xml`?

I'm currently using the console tag like below without the external pattern file in `log4j2.xml`.

```xml
<Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
 <PatternLayout>
   <pattern>{"level":"%p","loggerName":"%c"}\n</pattern>
 </PatternLayout>
</Console>
```

Comment: What pattern are you trying to obtain? With [Log4j JSON Template Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) you probably won't need to rewrite `com.abc.logging.MyJsonLayout`.

Comment: I have some custom pattern with several key value pairs in that file...I cannot rebuild the same pattern using the `Log4j JSON Template Layout` you have mentioned, because If I later change the pattern in that file, I need it to be reflected in the logs as well..

Comment: Since `com.abc.logging.MyJsonLayout` is not a file, but a class name, can you clarify how your custom Logback layout retrieves the pattern from an external file (e.g. add the code of your class to the question)?